# Install Ubuntu truncate command to Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: mac-osx, ubuntu-12.04

Is there any way to install Ubuntu's truncate command to Mac OS X 10.7 in order to use the command in Terminal shell?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a shell script that makes sure of truncate function, which I want to try it in local Mac.

Comment: The question is posed as 'how to install truncate', but a workable answer might be `:> file` which works equally well on Ubuntu and macOS. (see alternate answer below)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This shouldn't really be in Server Fault, probably Super User or Ask Different, but you can install a lot of binaries by using homebrew, found here:

[Link](https://brew.sh/)

Firstly you'll need to install command line tools for Xcode, which will probably require you to purchase it if you havn't already.

Once you've done this, run:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

To install homebrew, then when it's installed, run:

```
brew install truncate
```

Comment: I found that truncate in homebrew is different than Ubuntu version. It does not have option flag.

Comment: There's also Fink: http://www.finkproject.org/ and Macports: http://www.macports.org/ you could try, before doing so run brew uninstall truncate, though.

Comment: Also would appreciate an upvote as, regardless of if it worked for you, I did provide a valid answer to your question :)

Comment: Now, using Yosemite the following solved for me (also using home brew: http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=6407.0

Answer (score 20):

Update:

As of March 2015 `truncate` is no longer available in Homebrew as a standalone formula.

As `truncate` is part of GNU Coreutils you should install it on OS X with the following command:

`> brew install coreutils`

After installation `truncate` will be available under the name `gtruncate`. Note that all programs from Coreutils will be available with the prefix `g`.

Comment: This should be the accepted Answer.

Comment: Looks like `truncate` is available in Homebrew again as its own formula.

Comment: ...and it's gone again.

Answer (score 5):

When `truncate` is not available you can often use `dd` instead. Eg.

Make a file full of zeros:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/youroutputfile bs=1m count=50
```

Truncate an existing file:

```
dd if=yourinputfile of=/tmp/youroutputfile bs=1k count=1
```

Note: the OS X `dd` uses lower case unit letters where GNU `dd` uses upper case.

Comment: `dd` can almost achieve the goal. Can `dd` truncate from the end of file? As I read from the man file of `dd`, I know that it can only be read from file beginning. How about I delete last 100 bytes from the file ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You'd have to do the target size calculation yourself by reading the file size first and subtracting 100 bytes.

Comment: I like this answer as it doesn't require me to install anything new.

Answer (score 1):

One point of consideration is if the truncated file is the same file or a new file with the same name. Of importance for log files that are still being written-to, or being `tail`ed.

`:> file`

Works on both *nix and macOS to truncate a file in-place.